# Create A Duplicate Value To Match An Input Value As Part Of A Form Validation - PHP

Tags: php

I have a form with a download counter on to track downloads. The functionality of this form and the related PHP all works as expected.

What I would like to do is have some functionality where if the `value` attribute of a hidden form input element is changed by the user (i.e in the dev tools) the related functionality (in this case the download counter) does not happen / is not submitted.

I have other form instances where this problem has been easy to solve because I've had a `$_SESSION` started on login that matches the user id, so when logged in, users can only amend their own details.

With the download counter though this is public facing (i.e. the user doesn't have to be logged in to download an image). I thought I could assign a variable that matched the `$db_image_id` that is fetched from the database (i.e has the same numeric value), and ensure this matches the value in the form hidden input element, but this doesn't seem to work?

Also, if there is a better way to approach this problem please do let me know.

Note: `$connection` is the database connection and `$db_image_id` is fetched from the MySQL database with `fetch()` and a PDO statement and then outputted into the form.

**PHP**

```
function downloadCounter() {

    global $connection;

    if (isset($_POST['download'], $_POST['image-id']) && is_numeric($_POST['image-id']) && $_POST['image-id'] > 0) {
       
        // value from hidden form element
        $imageID = $_POST['image-id'];

        // ** THIS IS THE BIT I THOUGHT WOULD WORK **

        // global $db_image_id;

        // CREATE ANOTHER VARIABLE THAT MATCHES '$db_image_id'
        // $tallyID = $db_image_id;
        // if ($tallyID != $imageID) {return;}

        try {
            $sql = "UPDATE imageposts SET downloads = downloads +1 WHERE image_id = :image_id";
            $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->execute([
                ':image_id' => $imageID
            ]);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <!-- when anchor link is clicked some javascript adds a click event to the button -->
    <a download href="image.jpg">Download Image</a>
    <button style="display:none" type="submit" name="download" title="Download"></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="image-id" value="<?php echo $db_image_id; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: I dont catch what you try to do. You can use sessions even if user does not need to log.

Comment: it will never be possible if FE(javascript, html) handles the download. What you can do is, have BE(PHP) serve the file and have a counter there instead of submitting the form.

Comment: @JoelCrypto each image instance has it's own form, there could be a large number of forms shown at any given time so having each form have its own $_SESSION isn't an option (if i've understood you correctly)?

Comment: @golangphp - it is done in the backend with PHP. The code example given is PHP. The only JS involved is a simple `click()` function on the download link to pass a click event onto the button which I haven't included because it isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: You get image name and id from the form, check if match and count.